# add to cart button not adding products in cart only in safari and edge browser

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Add to cart button not adding products in cart only in safari and edge browser
on other all browser working fine please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got it fixed by updating all plugins and wordpress core version.. thanks alot